# Modifying a nested object with jq

Tags: json, object, jq

I'm using jq to modify a json file but I'm having issues with nested objects. I need to find an object inside of an array of objects and then modify a nested object inside of that object. I'm able to find the correct object and modify a key/value pair inside of that object, but modifying a key/value pair inside of a nested object is giving me issues. I’m sure there is a way to accomplish this with jq but I cannot find it. For this example I'm trying to modify the "pos_color" value for the track where the label is AX11S1.bw.

```
# find correct object and change key/value command ( this will change the min_score from 0 to 200 )
jq '.tracks |= map(if .label=="AX11S1.bw" then . + {"min_score":"200"} else . end)' trackList.json 

# Example JSON
{
  "tracks": [
    {
      "style": {
        "clip_marker_color": "red",
        "neg_color": "#005EFF",
        "pos_color": "blue",
        "height": 100
      },
      "variance_band": true,
      "max_score": 100,
      "label": "AX11S1.bw",
      "min_score": 0
    },
    {
      "style": {
        "clip_marker_color": "red",
        "neg_color": "#005EFF",
        "pos_color": "blue",
        "height": 100
      },
      "variance_band": true,
      "max_score": 100,
      "label": "AX11S2.bw",
      "min_score": 0
    },
    {
      "style": {
        "clip_marker_color": "red",
        "neg_color": "#005EFF",
        "pos_color": "blue",
        "height": 100
      },
      "variance_band": true,
      "max_score": 100,
      "label": "AX11S3.bw",
      "min_score": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.tracks |= map(if .label=="AX11S1.bw" 
               then .style.pos_color = "NEW VALUE" 
               else . end)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!